# Firebase Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got `FCM` working, but I can't get the traditional banner notifications working.

Here's what I have in my `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder {
  var window: UIWindow?

  override init() {
    super.init()    
    FIRApp.configure()
  }
}

// MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
extension AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { _, _ in })
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(tokenRefreshNotification), name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
    return true
  }

  func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
      print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }

    connectToFcm()
  }

  func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { error in
      if error != nil {
        print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
      } else {
        print("Connected to FCM.")
      }
    }
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    connectToFcm()
  }
}

// MARK: - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
  }
}

// MARK:
extension AppDelegate: FIRMessagingDelegate {
  func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("FIRMessagingRemoteMessage Received: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
  }
}
```

Everything is configured according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-audience). I'm getting console outputs when I send messages to my app via the notifications console on Firebase.

However, banners don't appear when notifications are sent. When the app is backgrounded, notifications don't appear to be sent either - only when the app is in the foreground.

Looking for help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the token generated successfully?

Comment: @NaveenRamanathan I just created a new property - `let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!` and that crashed. I guess it did not generate successfully. 

The docs never mentioned the token though...

Comment: The token will be generated after tokenRefreshNotification is called. If you try to get the token before being generated, your app will crash. Is tokenRefreshNotification method called and does print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)") print the token?

Comment: It did not print the token.

Comment: Whats the iOS version of the device you are testing with

Comment: I'm testing on my iPhone 7, on iOS 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling method swizzling.

`Add FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to info.plist and set it to NO`.

Then add this code to the app delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
  FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox)
}
```

Delete your app from the device and reinstall it. 
please test if `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called. If its called, now try sending a notification from the firebase console.

Comment: Works now, but I don't understand. Didn't iOS 10 introduce `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to deprecate the usage of the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods?

Comment: No they did not https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622958-application. application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is still in use and its totally different from UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate. Firebase uses method swizzling to handle didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken. Sometimes this doesn't work. UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate gives callbacks to handle push notification related user interactions. That is after the push is received. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!